# Jquery on/off event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was given code that looks like

```
this.$dropdownButton.off('click.fpmenu').on('click.fpmenu', function (evt) {});
```

where

`this.$dropdownButton`

Is a valid button element.

However, at the same place if I search for .fpmenu (`$('.fpmenu')`), I don't get anything.

Is the on/off events that I am trying to attach to `$dropdownButton` suppose to be a delegate of the click function of fpmenu? If it can't find fpmenu, would it cause the event not to be attached?

Comment: 'click.fpmenu' is the event name, not an element selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fpmenu` is the namespace of the event handler. This enables jQuery to remove specific event handlers, without changing others.

See [Event names and namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) in jQuery's `.on()` documentation.

**Example** - click button and see which event handler is called

```js
var button = $('button');

button.on('click.fpmenu', function () { console.log('fpmenu'); }); // add fpmenu named event

button.on('click.somethingElse', function () { console.log('somethingElse'); }); // add somethingElse named event

button.off('click.fpmenu'); // remove fpmenu named event
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```